# Gradle sync failed: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.2.2 available for offline mode

Tags: android, gradle

I just updated my android studio to  3.6.1 and this happening. I tried to download and add gradle manually in .gradle/wrapper/dist but still no issue

down below is my gradle-wrapper.properties file details

```
#Sat Mar 07 19:16:09 PKT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

click on AS  Left side panel -> **Gradle**
click on **Toggle offline mode icon**

as shown in screenShot and make sure you have working internet(gradle file size generally above 300MB)

[image]

Comment: That was the button I was searching for !! JazakAllah